# Router Flux - how to disable automatic text on the tab bar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

[image]

This is the result. I'd like to render text and icons on my own. So I need to disable the automatic generated text for the tabs. Any suggestion ?

Also, the text color is not changing to red when it's active (TabIcon function).

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text} from 'react-native'
import {Router, Scene,Stack, Modal} from 'react-native-router-flux'

// Scenes
import BrowseUser from '../scenes/BrowseUser'
import Notifications from '../scenes/Notifications'
import Search from '../scenes/Search'
import Timeline from '../scenes/Timeline'

const TabIcon = ({selected,title}) => {
  return(<Text style={{color: selected ? 'red ' : 'black'}}>{title} 
</Text>)
}

export default props => (
<Router>
    <Stack key="root" hideNavBar>
        <Scene key='main' icon={TabIcon} tabs={true} initial tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#00FF00'}}>
            <Scene key='timeline' component={Timeline} title='Timeline'/>
            <Scene key='browseUser' component={BrowseUser} title='BrowseUser'/>
            <Scene key='search' component={Search} title='Search'/>
            <Scene key='notifications' component={Notifications} title='Notifications'/>
        </Scene>
    </Stack>
</Router>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding

> So I need to disable the automatic generated text for the tabs. Any suggestion ?

The componenet supports the prop `showLabel` so you can set it to false `showLabel={false}` and that will not display the title of the tabbed scenes.

Regarding

> Also, the text color is not changing to red when it's active (TabIcon function).

The prop passed on selection is `focused` not "selected". So it should be

```
const TabIcon = ({ focused,title }) => 
  (<Text style={{color: focused ? 'red ' : 'black'}}>{title}</Text>)
```